# Python3 hangs with os.walk() and multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, os.walk

I found a code for file scanning that using multiprocessing module. Everything works fine with python 2.7 on Linux, but the same code doesent works on python 3 on Linux, doens't work on python 2 or python 3 on Windows and i don't know how to fix it and asking for your help :(

This is the link where code of script is located: https://gist.github.com/samuelsh/a8be5bc93fcd7ff256c9

- In Python 2 or 3 on Windows script is crashing and python interpreter it showing to me that i need to use freeze_support() but all my changes doesn't give me a success when i adding freeze_support() function into script code

  - In Python 2 or 3 in Bash subsystem on Windows process hangs in explore_path() function after executing this line of code dirpath = dirpath_queue.get()
  - In Python 3 on Linux the same problem with hanging after dirpath = dirpath_queue.get() in explore_path()
  - In Python 2 on Linux works perfect.

I have no assumptions why process is hangs on Python 3 if the same code is working on Python 2. Tryed to change map_async() to imap_unordered() function but it doesn't help.

Can anyone help me to start that code on Python 3?

Comment: I wouldn't trust a source which contains typos in the file name of the source code (`dir_wlaker_multiprocess.py`). If the author failed to name his file properly, he may be also failed to debug his code?

Comment: But i want to make this code work into python3 and asked for help here :) I don't care what author did. That code is works perfetc on python2 on Linux and on python3 that code is hanging after 1 iteration. Can you help me to fix that?

Comment: Solved! The problem was in `os.walk(dirpath).next()` because in Python2 it works nice but in Python3 you need to replae it with `next(os.walk(dirpath))`